# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2

Tags: android, maven

I stuck with following error:

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
 com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources (execution: 
 default-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)

Comment: Can you share your pom or at least the configuration section of the android maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled STS and that error get vanished.